# failed to add a file to gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file I have to be ignored by git 
I have done this actions

1. git rm --cached `path_to_file/filename.py`
2. added `path_to_file/filename.py` to .gitignore

The file does not show up on git indeed but when I switch branches or even switch back to the original branch, the file is gone.

Comment: After performing the two steps above, what was the state of things?  Did `filename.py` still exist as an untracked file?

Comment: No, it does not appear there

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  Did it exist _before_ running the two steps?

Comment: I don't know. now I've tried to add it and it sticks across branches. I'll keep monitoring

Comment: OK.  If you can't reproduce this question then consider closing it.

Comment: I can't seem to find the right reason to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is: `git rm --cached path_to_file/filename.py` would have worked even if the file was *not* present in the workspace (but was tracked by git)

So if you don't see that file after the git rm --cached step, that means it was deleted.
If you restore it and it does remain when switching branch, that means it is untracked (you can check that with `git check-ignore -v -- path_to_file/filename.py`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven't managed to reproduce the question. If it will happen again today, I'll update. If not, I'll vote to close this question.